# Make conforming Delaunay - Wrong (?) points inserted

Tags: cgal, triangulation, terrain, delaunay

I'm using CGAL 2D Delaunay triangulation to define a terrain. I can't use the `terrain` class because my triangulation has constraints and they can't be used on terrain or 3D triangulations. (That's what I see so far, since there are no terrain properties or 3D triangulation classes). Due to the constraints I'm using the `make_conforming_delaunay_2` function to refine the triangulation. I have a problem when using this function. Everything is compiling and running OK, but the problem is with the results:

1. The function is inserting some points out of any existing triangle face. Is this correct?
2. Since it is a terrain I need the elevation of these inserted points. Is there any way to make CGAL tell me what triangle face these inserted points are in, so that I could calculate its elevation? I expected the points only in existing triangles faces.
3. Is there anyway even in a 2d triangulation to use 3D points? (So that the interpolated points will come with the elevation already calculated.)

Comment: Did you try [CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Projection__traits__xy__3.html) like in [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title14)?

Comment: It seems exactly what I´m looking for!!!! I´ll try it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class [CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Projection__traits__xy__3.html) like in this [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title14).